# cheerio.load() expects a string node_modules/cheerio/lib/load.js:74:1

Tags: typescript, gmail, cypress, gmail-api

I am working Cypress Typescript and have integrated gmail-tester in my automation. The issue im facing is very weird. I am trying to click on a button from the email Everything seems to be workinf prefectly fine even if i click on the button manually i.e. by entering the URL the screen is displayed but while im doing this with by fetching the button URL and clicking nothing seems to be working!!

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import fs from 'fs';


describe("Email assertion:", () => {
  it("Using gmail_tester.get_messages(), look for an email with specific subject and link in email body", function () {
    cy.task("gmail:get-messages", {
      options: {
        from: "test@test.com",
        subject: "Account confirmation",
        include_body: true,
      },
    }).then((emails: any) => {
      assert.isAtLeast(emails.length, 1, "Expected to find at least one email, but none were found!");
      assert.isTrue(emails[0].subject.indexOf("Account confirmation") >= 0, "Found email with subject 'Account confirmation'!");
      const body = emails[0].html;
      const emailContent = emails.html;
      // Use Cheerio to extract the link URL from the email content
      const $ = cheerio.load(emailContent);
      const linkUrl = $('a[href^="http://localhost:3000/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail"]').attr('href');
      // Use cy.visit() to navigate to the link URL
      cy.visit(linkUrl);
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

I tired multiple option, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It works for me - what is your emialcontent?

Comment: Most likely you made a typo - `.const body = emails[0].html` but `const emailContent = emails.html` - make that consistent, and your error will vanish.

Comment: hi @AlPugliese i tried but getting same error, would mind sharing your code maybe i missed something?

Comment: @AlPugliese my issue still persists! i don't know what is going wrong it seems to provide all the validation but not clicking on the link I made the changes you asked for it still doesn't seems to be working, can i use anything else besides cheerio?

Comment: hi @AlPugliese i look forward to your response, how is this working for you, even after adding a string it is not clicking the button
const $ = load("Verify Email Address", emailContent);

Comment: I hope you can get there eventually, it will take some debugging skills. Clearly you've not found the correct string because the error message tells you that. But I can definitely tell you that `cheerio.load(emailContent)` works if you give it a proper string, so that gives you something to go on. But unfortunately, as your question stands, there are no further clues to solve your problem remotely.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer precisely because there are debugging details missing, but since you could not resolve from my comment here is what you need to look at.

It all depends on what you receive in `emails` from `.then((emails: any)`.

The error message says `emailContent` isn't a string, so you need to take a look at `emails` and work out how to get HTML as a string for `cheerio.load(<some-html-string-here>)`

- the name `emails` implies multiple emails received, so use `emails[0]` to get a single email
- you have confirmed `emails[0]` is correct above with `assert.isTrue(emails[0].subject.indexOf("Account confirmation")`
- `const body = emails[0].html` should be checked to see if

  - `body` is a string
  - `body` contains the link `a[href^="http://localhost:3000...`

If all checks out, use `cheerio.load(body)`, otherwise you need to make adjustments depending on what you see in variables.

Comment: hi @AlPugliese i look forward to your response, how is this working for you, even after adding a string it is not clicking the button
const $ = load("Verify Email Address", emailContent);